# Installing Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux

I am running Linux Crunchbang 64 bit. I'm trying to update my Java and JDK version.

When I run the command

> Java -version

I get

> java version "1.6.0_27"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1~deb7u1)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

And I'm trying to run code that works on java 7 but it appears I have java 6.

I downloaded the JDK (Linux x64) from [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) site and the file name was 'jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz'.

To install it I opened terminal and typed

> sudo apt-get install jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz

And got

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz'

Comment: You're using the wrong tool. apt-get checks the repos for the package, you already downloaded the package.

Answer (score 1):

You already installed `OpenJDK`. If you want to install the tarball, do not use `apt-get`. Instead, extract it:

```
tar -xvzf jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz && cd jdk-7u45-linux-x64
```

and in that folder, check the readme and install.

Comment: I've done that, but the readme doesn't say how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Unpacking `tar.gz` file isn't quite the appropriate way for installing software on Debian-based Linux distributions, especially when it comes to such system-level software.

If you would like to change the level of Java installed on your machine, you should use your platform's package provisioning tool. Try `apt-get install aptitude`, then run `aptitude` as superuser. Through `aptitude`, install the appropriate level of Java.

Comment: aptitude is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.

Comment: Good. Now run aptitude and use it to look for your desired Java version.